# Cannot get SQL for: Subtract

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite.net

I'm trying to make a query with SQLite.NET package on Xamarin.

```
public static List<Place> searchForPlace(double lat, double lng)
{
    var query = conn.Table<GPSPoint>().Where(v => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(v.lat - lat, 2) - Math.Pow(v.lng - lng, 2)) < 5);

    List<Place> l = new List<Place>();

    foreach (var gpsPoint in query) // the foreach statement causes the error System.NotSupportedException: Cannot get SQL for: Subtract
    {
        var queryPlaces = conn.Table<Place>().Where(v => v.ID == gpsPoint.ID);
        foreach (var place in queryPlaces)
            l.Add(place);
        break;
    }
    return l;
}
```

but my code gives me this error `System.NotSupportedException: Cannot get SQL for: Subtract`.

This is the code I use for init the database

```
public DatabaseConnection()
{
    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    conn = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "navigationApp.db"));
    conn.CreateTable<GPSPoint>();
    conn.CreateTable<Place>();
}
```

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your where clause.

```
   var query = conn.Table<GPSPoint>().Where(v => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(v.lat - lat, 2) - Math.Pow(v.lng - lng, 2)) < 5);
```

Because LINQ To Sql evaluates this expression it also trys to evaluate Math.Sqrt, Math.Pow and the **Subtract**. You need to load the data and then evaluate it, because you cannot execute the calculation in SQL in that way.

This would be a possible solution. Probably you can define another bool clause to sort out some points beforehand.

```
var gpsPoints = conn.Table<GPSPoint>();
var validPoints = gpsPoints.Where(v => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(v.lat - lat, 2) - Math.Pow(v.lng - lng, 2)) < 5);
```

Comment: Your code gives me the error `TableQuery<GPSPoint> does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'TableQuery<GPSPoint>' could be found`

Comment: You need to call `ToList()` with a generic argument I guess. `ToList<GPSPoint>()`;

Comment: I can't call `ToList` method at all. [there're no definitions for this method](http://imgur.com/LAMZAgp).

Comment: SQLite.net is quite a bit confusing in this case. Beside all other mappers SQLite.net retrieves all the data from a table with out this ToList call so if you remove it and just use conn.Table<GPSPoint>(); you should be able to load all data.

Comment: Can you give closer information? Compile error or runtime error?

Comment: It's a compile error. The methods `ToList` & `ToList<...>` are not defined in `TableQuery<GPSPoint>` .

Comment: Referring to my comment about 1 hour ago plese remove the tolist and call it like i edited in my answer post. Please try the actual version I've written in my original post